# How to catch an word after a mark on the string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string like this: `"something_before cl: something_after"`

`cl:` is my mark and I want to catch every word after it. In this case I want to catch the string `"something_after"`. How can I do it?

Currently I doing this: `commit_log.scan(/cl: .*/)[0].gsub("cl: ", "")`. But this code is ugly, I looking for a better way to rewrite it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

split with the mark

```
"something_before cl: something_after".split("cl: ").last
=> "something_after"
```

or use a lookbehind asseration

```
"something_before cl: something_after".scan /(?<=cl: ).*/
=> [" something_after"]
```